# Can I use one load balance for my setup?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I have

- frontend website https://www.example.com/*
- backend app https://app.example.com/*
- backend api https://api.example.com/*
- CDN https://cdn.example.com/*
- backend services (interal) https://services.example.com/*

All servers use port 443, using just one load balancer, how would I setup the load balancer's target group in AWS? If its unable to setup my setup, how do I fix it to make it work with elastic load balancer?

Comment: The cert supplied by that ALB may have to cover all of the hostnames.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/).

From the FAQ

**Content-Based Routing**
If your application is composed of several individual services, an Application Load Balancer can route a request to a service based on the content of the request.

**Host-based Routing**

You can route a client request based on Host field of the HTTP header allowing you to route to multiple domains from the same load balancer.

etc

Comment: Solution : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/introducing-application-load-balancer-unlocking-and-optimizing-architectures/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Amazon CloudFront as your CDN? If so you would configure your custom DNS address https://www.example.com to point to the hostname provided for your CloudFront endpoint (CloudFront will need to be adjusted so it excepts the custom name). The cloudfront endpoint would forward all 443 requests to the Elastic Load Balancer that will in turn pass requests to your ELBs Target Group that will be made up of your FrontEnd web instances.

Hope this helps.

Mike.

Comment: Currently not using cloudfront CDN, will move to cloudfront, but dont know how to setup target group with sub domains! (only seems like target group supports path?)